# UnknownElementException on Java 17 record class

Tags: java, maven, java-17

With excitement I downloaded Java 17 today and got a simple record class

```java
public record TestCls(Party producer, Party client, Party server) {}
```

However when doing `mvn compile`, it throws me error
`Fatal error compiling: javax.lang.model.element.UnknownElementException: Unknown element: "com.xxx.TestCls"`

I double checked `java -version` and it looks right to me:

```
openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-2724)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Would anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance!

---

Supplements:
my maven version is `3.5.4`.
maven settings in pom file:

```xml
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

I'm using Intellij `2021.1.2` on M1 chip. But I tried mvn compile in terminal and it gives me same error.
The `Party` class is defined in the same project.

The whole pom file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xxx</name>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <version>5.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <url>...</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-releases</id>
            <url>...</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-releases</id>
            <url>...</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <url>...</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

and the stacktrace with `mvn compile -e`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project reporting-event-spring-boot-starter: Fatal error compiling: javax.lang.model.element.UnknownElementException: Unknown element: "com.xxx.TestCls" -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project reporting-event-spring-boot-starter: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:796)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: javax.lang.model.element.UnknownElementException: Unknown element: "com.xxx.TestCls"
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.lang.model.element.UnknownElementException: Unknown element: "com.xxx.TestCls"
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper (JavacTaskImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: javax.lang.model.element.UnknownElementException: Unknown element: "com.xxx.TestCls"
    at javax.lang.model.util.AbstractElementVisitor6.visitUnknown (AbstractElementVisitor6.java:129)
    at javax.lang.model.util.ElementKindVisitor6.visitTypeAsRecord (ElementKindVisitor6.java:231)
    at javax.lang.model.util.ElementKindVisitor6.visitType (ElementKindVisitor6.java:160)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.accept (Symbol.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor.process (ConstraintValidationProcessor.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1382)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations (JavaCompiler.java:1234)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile (JavaCompiler.java:916)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0 (JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper (JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

---

Posting ChatGPT’s answer here:
It looks like you are using an older version of Maven (3.5.4) that does not support the new features introduced in Java 17, such as records. In order to use Java 17 features with Maven, you will need to use a more recent version of Maven that includes support for Java 17.

You can check the compatibility of Maven versions with Java versions in the Maven documentation [1]. According to the documentation, Maven 3.6.3 and later versions support Java 17.

Therefore, to use Java 17 features with Maven, you will need to upgrade to a more recent version of Maven, such as version 3.6.3 or later. Once you have upgraded to a compatible version of Maven, you should be able to compile and use your record class without encountering the Unknown element error.

[1] https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html#Java_Versions

Comment: Perhaps updating Maven helps.

Comment: How's the configuration of the maven-compiler-plugin in your pom.xml?

Comment: Are you using an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)? If so, which one, and what version? And, edit your Question to show your entire POM file.

Comment: Did you define a `Party` class? Or, where is that `Party` class coming from?

Comment: Please show a complete example. What line and file is the error message coming from?

Comment: First I strongly recommend to upgrade your maven-compiler-plugin furthermore I would recommend to upgrade Maven itself and you should remove the repositories configuration from your pom file and move that to your settings.xml file instead....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly it would be safer to upgrade the version of Maven and the maven-compiler-plugin as recommended in the comments. Nevertheless the interesting part in the compiler error stack trace is:

```
Caused by: javax.lang.model.element.UnknownElementException: Unknown element: "com.xxx.TestCls"
    at javax.lang.model.util.AbstractElementVisitor6.visitUnknown (AbstractElementVisitor6.java:129)
    at javax.lang.model.util.ElementKindVisitor6.visitTypeAsRecord (ElementKindVisitor6.java:231)
    at javax.lang.model.util.ElementKindVisitor6.visitType (ElementKindVisitor6.java:160)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.accept (Symbol.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor.process (ConstraintValidationProcessor.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
```

It seems to me that [`org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/annotation-processor/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/ap/ConstraintValidationProcessor.java#L119) is invoking a [visitor](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/annotation-processor/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/ap/ConstraintValidationProcessor.java#L99) that is of type [`ConstraintAnnotationVisitor`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/annotation-processor/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/ap/internal/ConstraintAnnotationVisitor.java) which itself extends [`AbstractElementVisitor`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/annotation-processor/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/ap/internal/AbstractElementVisitor.java) which in turn extends [`ElementKindVisitor8`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.compiler/share/classes/javax/lang/model/util/AbstractElementVisitor8.java). The latter is coming from the JDK and seems targeting Java 8 source, whereas records appear to be supported by [`AbstractElementVisitor14`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.compiler/share/classes/javax/lang/model/util/AbstractElementVisitor14.java).

This leads me to doubt that this could be an issue in hibernate-validator's `ConstraintAnnotationVisitor` which does not support records? Maybe an issue on their GitHub repo with a more complete reproduction would help more.

Comment: Leads you to doubt, or leads you to believe? I imagine you meant the latter?

Comment: This is correct - the hibernate-validator-annotation-processor doesn't currently (2022-06-07) have a released version that supports records. Support was added in this PR - https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/pull/1263.

Comment: In my case, I had the same issue coming from `hibernate-validator`. But it was a **transitive dependency** because I included `jakarta.validation-api`. Anyway the pull request, seems to be merged, so this issue should be resolved in the newest release of `hibernate-validator`.